# Calculating the mean differences of subarrays

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity

I'm trying to devise a way to calculate the **mean differences** (the absolute average differences between any two values in a set), of sub-arrays (starting from arbitrary indices) in an `int` array. I'll be placing the bounds of each subarray in to "buckets" of differing mean difference magnitudes.

The problem is, I can't find an efficient (better than \$O(n^3)\$) way of doing this. Would anyone mind helping me make the code more efficient (at least better than \$O(n^2)\$)?.

The calculations are performed server-side upon user request from my web-app. If making it more efficient isn't possible, would it be advisable to adopt a solution that doesn't involve modifying the computation, such as:

- Keep this inefficient implementation and include a disclaimer stating it may take some time to complete
- Transfer the calculations to several daemon threads which will
  perform the process on the entire user base and store the results in
  the database, which will be returned to the users (returned results
  may not be up-to-date)

I'm currently at a crossroads and am not sure which route I should take.

**Pseudocode of main function:**

> ```
> /*The purpose of the main function is to store the mean differences of  
> sub-arrays in a given array, making the sure the stored sub-arrays are as 
> long as possible*/
>
> for i in dataArray
>  loop through all j (j starting from i + 1) in dataArray 
>     get mean difference of values in between indexes i and j
>     get int value of mean difference (bucket)
>     if bucket != (bucket of mean difference of values 
>        in between indexes i and j - 1), store i and j in bucket
> ```

**Main function**:

```
public static HashMap<Integer, Stack<HashMap<String, Integer>>> calculateMeanDifferences(ArrayList<Integer> dataArrayList)
{
    //Each key maps to a stack which will hold HashMaps containing the bounding indices of subArrays which have mean differences that round to the key
    HashMap<Integer, Stack<HashMap<String, Integer>>> meanDifferenceBucketHashMap = new HashMap<Integer, Stack<HashMap<String, Integer>>>();

    long size = dataArrayList.size();

    Integer previousMeanDifferenceBucket = null;
    Integer currentMeanDifferenceBucket = null;

    double currentMeanDifference = 0;

    //Major loop which starts the mean difference calculations from every index
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        //Minor loop which calculates the mean differences for sub-arrays of increasing length starting from i.
        for(int j = i + 2; j < size + 1; j++)
        {
            currentMeanDifference =  calculateMeanDifference(new ArrayList(dataArrayList.subList(i, j)));
            currentMeanDifferenceBucket = (int)Math.round(currentMeanDifference);

            //Ensure longest possible sub-array is recorded (so, for all i and j, if both subList(i,j-1) and subList(i, j) are recorded, they will be in different buckets)
            if((previousMeanDifferenceBucket != null && previousMeanDifferenceBucket != currentMeanDifferenceBucket) || j == size)
            {
                HashMap<String, Integer> previousSubArrayBoundsHashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                previousSubArrayBoundsHashMap.put("start", i);
                previousSubArrayBoundsHashMap.put("onePastEnd", j);

                if(!meanDifferenceBucketHashMap.containsKey(previousMeanDifferenceBucket))
                    meanDifferenceBucketHashMap.put(previousMeanDifferenceBucket, new Stack<HashMap<String, Integer>>());
                else
                    meanDifferenceBucketHashMap.get(previousMeanDifferenceBucket).push(previousSubArrayBoundsHashMap);
            }

            previousMeanDifferenceBucket = currentMeanDifferenceBucket;
        }

        previousMeanDifferenceBucket = currentMeanDifferenceBucket = null;
    }

    return meanDifferenceBucketHashMap;
}
```

**Sub-function** (not necessary to look over, just know it is \$O(n)\$ for my use case (all values guaranteed to be in the set [0,5])):

```
public static double calculateMeanDifference(ArrayList<Integer> valuesArrayList)
{
    HashMap<Integer, Double> valueCountsHashMap = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();

    double size = valuesArrayList.size();

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int currentValue = valuesArrayList.get(i);

        if(!valueCountsHashMap.containsKey(currentValue))
            valueCountsHashMap.put(currentValue, new Double(1));
        else
            valueCountsHashMap.put(currentValue, valueCountsHashMap.get(currentValue)+ 1);
    }

    double sum = 0;

    for(Map.Entry<Integer, Double> valueCountKeyValuePair : valueCountsHashMap.entrySet())
    {
        int currentValue = valueCountKeyValuePair.getKey();
        Double currentCount = valueCountKeyValuePair.getValue();

        for(Map.Entry<Integer, Double> valueCountKeyValuePair1 : valueCountsHashMap.entrySet())
        {
            int loopValue = valueCountKeyValuePair1.getKey();
            Double loopCount = valueCountKeyValuePair1.getValue();

            sum += (currentValue != loopValue ? Math.abs(currentValue - loopValue) * loopCount * currentCount : 0);
        }
    }

    return new Double( sum/ (size * (size - 1)));
}
```

Comment: Could you, instead of just posting your code, provide some (links to) hints on the actual math which you are trying to implement, as well as pseudocode of your algorithm? This would make it much easier to see if there are any shortcuts you are missing.

Comment: @TomasLycken: The methodology behind calculating the mean difference average can be found in the first img in my SO post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931515/translating-equivalent-formulas-in-to-code-isnt-giving-correct-results/8931761). This isn't of particular interest though, it will always O(N). I'll include pseudocode of what i'm trying to do right now. It'll be up in a couple of minutes

Comment: Mean difference calculation is O(n^2) surely?

Comment: @TimGee: Depending on the implementation (see the linked post in my first comment). Using this particular function with random values in the dataArray, it will be O(n^2). For my use case, however, it is O(n), since all the values in the data array are guarenteed to have values in the set [0,5].

Comment: Ah okay. I think what you might need is an incremental/online calculation for mean difference. I know that's not sufficient for an answer, so I'll just leave that as a comment... ;)

Comment: It's still not clear what you are generally trying to achieve and what buckets are exactly.

Comment: Your problem looks very parallelizable: each pass of the outer loop seems to be independent of the others.  Might start with that.

Comment: @cyborg: The buckets are simply categories that contain subarrays that have mean differences that round to a given integer. My objective is still unclear? Can you be a bit more specific as to what is unclear?

Comment: @Kevin I can't speak for cyborg, but here's what gets me confused.  In the pseudocode, you talk of "looping over j", which to me says that j is a int that varies (as it does in your code) but then "get mean difference of dataArray(i, j)".  If i is a single number (at a time) and so is j, what is the talk of "mean" difference.  There's only a single difference.  There's a k missing somewhere.  Also, in the actual code, why does j start at i+2, not i+1?

Comment: @user949300: Sorry for the confusion. In the pseudocode, "get mean difference of dataArray(i, j)" means "get the mean difference of the values contained between index i and index j (inclusive). In the actual code, j starts at "i + 2" because we want to process sub-arrays with at least two elements (the mean difference of a one element set is useless). The .subList() function takes the beginning index, and one PAST the end index of the selection. So if I wanted a sub-list of size 2 starting from index 0, I would use .subList(0, 2)

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly (`sum(abs(v1-v2) for i,v1 in enumerate(a) for v2 in a[i+1:])/(len(a)*(len(a+1))/2)`), this is doable in O(nlogn) time, O(n) auxiliary space with a balanced search tree structure (keeping extra metadata, e.g. sum of elements in the subtrees rooted at each node).

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do, but rounding the mean of differences to an integer looks quite wrong.

Comment: @toto2: Sorry if it is still confusing. I've gone over the pseudocode several times and think it describes the procedure at least somewhat adequately. Even though I've changed what I'm measuring and no longer need to use the method, I'd still like to make was I was trying to accomplish clear for others who may want to analyze data in a similar way in the future. So, what exactly is it you don't understand? The rounding of the mean differences is done merely to categorize sub-arrays with similar mean differences together

Comment: Sorry, I just reread your question and I'm still as confused.  I think you should start over with a new question if you want help from someone.  The problem is not as much the code as not explaining what you are trying to do.  It would help to describe what it is that you are trying to do in very general terms and what it is used for.  You did try to explain by replying to comments, but it's a mess now.

Answer (score 7):

The first optimisation is to avoid using `Double` and `Integer` when you really want `double` and `int` You can use Trove4j to act as collection of these types. Additionally I wouldn't use double when you mean to use int, e.g. for counts which can only be whole numbers.

I would also avoid counting the combinations twice. e.g. if you have an array of two you compare both a1 - a2 and a2 - a1 which should be the same.

Can you make any assumptions on the range of int values?

---

This example

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    Random rand = new Random(1);
    int size = 100000;
    TIntArrayList valuesArrayList = new TIntArrayList(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        valuesArrayList.add(rand.nextInt(size) - rand.nextInt(size));
    }
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    double d = calculateMeanDifference(valuesArrayList);
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("Took %.3f seconds to calculate d=%.3f for size=%,d values%n", time / 1e9, d, size);
}

public static double calculateMeanDifference(TIntArrayList valuesArrayList) {
    final TIntIntHashMap counts = new TIntIntHashMap();
    valuesArrayList.forEach(new TIntProcedure() {
        @Override
        public boolean execute(int value) {
            counts.adjustOrPutValue(value, 1, 1);
            return true;
        }
    });

    final int[] uniqueValues = new int[counts.size()], uniqueCounts = new int[counts.size()];
    counts.forEachEntry(new TIntIntProcedure() {
        int i = 0;
        @Override
        public boolean execute(int a, int b) {
            uniqueValues[i] = a;
            uniqueCounts[i++] = b;
            return true;
        }
    });
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < uniqueValues.length; i++) {
        int vi = uniqueValues[i];
        int ci = uniqueCounts[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            int counts2 = ci * uniqueCounts[j];
            sum += Math.abs(vi - uniqueValues[j]) * counts2;
        }
    }

    return 2.0 * sum / valuesArrayList.size() / (valuesArrayList.size() - 1);
}
```

prints

```
Took 12.173 seconds to calculate d=46786.434 for size=100,000 values
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. In actuality, I'll be processing an array of objects from which the values will be retrieved, so I won't be able to use TIntArrayList. And yes, an important assumption can be made for the values processed: they all will have values in the range [0,5]. I'm a bit confused as to why `count` is being increased by the product of every two unique counts processed. In the return statement, what is `count` supposed to represent? In the official formula, the denominator is `N * (N - 1)`, where `N`, in your code, is the summation of all values in `uniqueCounts[]`

Comment: Additionally, in your code you loop through the map just to insert unique values and counts in to seperate arrays, then iterate through them. I know in theory iterating through arrays is faster than going over each `Map.entry`, but won't having to iterate through 100,000 elements once (map, nested loop in my code)  beat doing it twice (creation of value& count arrays, then nested loop for processing of the arrays) every time? Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah. I assume your stance is that the avoidance of calculating `|a[i] - a[j]|` when `|a[j] - a[i]|` is already known may offset the extra processing done by your code. I suppose I could use a map of pairs to store and re-use the calculated mini-sums to avoid doing that in my code

Comment: You are right that count is not strictly needed.  Since you mutliplying by the values, I don't see how they can be objects.  You are performing O(n^2) lookups so iterating to build an array isn't significant. It also simplifies accessing `i < j`

Comment: What I mean to say is that the argument array will actually be an array of Maps, each of which will contain the value of interest. So if `mapArray` is the input array, `mapArray[i].get("value")` for each `i` would give the values we are computing the mean difference for. So, the input parameter can't be of type `TIntArrayList`. In any case, your method is SUPER fast. I'll definately be using it. Thanks.

Comment: You can copy all the `mapArray[i].get("value")` into a TIntArrayList

Answer (score 1):

Let us have two functions:

```
aggr_sum(a, i, j) : |a[i]-a[j]| +....+ |a[j-1]-a[j]|
sum_difference(a,i,j): sum of difference of all elements from a[i]...a[j]
```

You can calculate aggr_sum for all values of i and j in O(n^2) time:

```
aggr_sum(a, i, j) = aggr_sum(a, i+1, j) + |a[i]-a[j]|
```

Now,

```
sum_difference(a,i,j) = sum_difference(a,i,j-1)+aggr_sum(a,i,j)
```

Which is also O(n^2)

Then you can divide sum_difference by count to get mean_difference.

Comment: I see. This is an attempt at the incremental approach that Tim Gee alluded to in a comment in the original post. However, I don't think that's possibe for the mean difference calculation. Once a new number is added in to the mix, you have to add:  `|(new number) - a[i]|` for all i in a to the sum of the previous mean difference calculation; you can't just perform one more calculation and increment the number of elements to divide by

Comment: @Kevin All I am saying is, when ever you add a new value you can update the calculations in O(n) steps (courtesy aggr_sum function). So even for incremental addition complexity is still O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up changing what I wanted to analyze in order decrease the amount of computation required. The solution is scenario-specific and involves analyzing groups of the array elements (represented as numbers in the original question, but are actually Objects containing these values) created on the same day, rather than analyzing all the contiguous subsets of the array.

A solution to the actual problem still hasn't been proposed, so I'll leave it unanswered in hopes that someone will come up with one!